# compute series with matrix and eigen value , eigen vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

series ${a_n}$ is define by $a_1=1$ , $a_2=5$ , $a_3=1$, $a_{n+3}=a_{n+2}+4a_{n+1}-4a_n$, ($n \geq 1$).

$\begin{pmatrix}a_{n+3} \\ a_{n+2} \\ a_{n+1} \\ \end{pmatrix}=B\begin{pmatrix}a_{n+2} \\ a_{n+1} \\ a_{n} \\ \end{pmatrix}$ 
find $B$

find general term of $a_n$ series

I found matrix b is $B=\begin{bmatrix}1&4&-4\\1&0&0\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix}$
but how can I find $a_n$?
I can compute that $\begin{pmatrix}a_{4} \\ a_{3} \\ a_{2} \\ \end{pmatrix}=B\begin{pmatrix}a_{3} \\ a_{2} \\ a_{1} \\ \end{pmatrix}$ 
$\begin{pmatrix}a_{4} \\ a_{3} \\ a_{2} \\ \end{pmatrix}=B\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 5 \\ 1 \\ \end{pmatrix}$  
$\begin{pmatrix}a_{5} \\ a_{4} \\ a_{3} \\ \end{pmatrix}=B^2\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 5 \\ 1 \\ \end{pmatrix}$

i see there is relation about this.

$a_{n+1}=B^na_n$ 
 suppose D is diagonal matrix that similar to B 
$a_{n+1}=TD^nT^- a_n$ 
which mean i need to find diagonal matrix and its inver to find $a_n$? is my assumption wrong?

Comment: Yes, so you need to diagonalize $B$.

Answer (score 1):

The formula is
$$
\begin{pmatrix} a_{n+2} \\ a_{n+1} \\ a_n \end{pmatrix}=B^{n-1}\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 5 \\ 1 \\ \end{pmatrix}
$$

**EDIT : PROOF**

By induction on $n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}$.

Let $n=1$, then we have 
$$
\begin{pmatrix} a_{3} \\ a_{2} \\ a_1 \end{pmatrix}=B^{0}\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 5 \\ 1 \\ \end{pmatrix}
$$
which is true.

Then suppose it is true until a certain index $n$. Then
$$
\begin{pmatrix} a_{n+3} \\ a_{n+2} \\ a_{n+1} \end{pmatrix}=B\begin{pmatrix} a_{n+2} \\ a_{n+1} \\ a_{n} \end{pmatrix}
$$
By hypothesis
$$\begin{pmatrix} a_{n+3} \\ a_{n+2} \\ a_{n+1} \end{pmatrix}=BB^{n-1}\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 5 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}=B^{n}\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 5 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Then the formula has been proved. Now, suppose you diagonalize $B$. Then you have
$$
\begin{pmatrix} a_{n+2} \\ a_{n+1} \\ a_n \end{pmatrix}=PD^{n-1}P^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 5 \\ 1 \\ \end{pmatrix}
$$

You know that $1$ is an eigenvalue because
$$
B\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ \end{pmatrix}
$$
Then you know that 
$$Tr(B)=1+\lambda_1+\lambda_2=1 \ \text{ and } \ \text{det}B=\lambda_1\lambda_2=-4 $$
Hence it comes $\lambda_1=2$ and $\lambda_2=-2$.

Now you have the three eigan value, and one eigenspace so you can deduce the two other eigenspace. You will find
$$D=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 &-2\end{pmatrix}$$
And
$$B-2I_3=\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 4 & -4\\ 1 & -2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 &-2\end{pmatrix}$$
Then it appears thart your eigenvector is $(4,2,1)$

$$B+2I_3=\begin{pmatrix} 3 & 4 & -4\\ 1 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 &2\end{pmatrix}$$
Then it appears thart your eigenvector is $(4,-2,1)$.

Then you have
$$
P=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 4 & 4\\ 1 & 2 & -2 \\ 1 & 1 &1\end{pmatrix}
$$
So finally computing $PDP^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 5 \\ 1 \\ \end{pmatrix}$ gives you $a_n$.

Comment: thankyou! but how do you know the formula? $\begin{pmatrix} a_{n+2} \\ a_{n+1} \\ a_n \end{pmatrix}=B^{n-1}\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 5 \\ 1 \\ \end{pmatrix}$ , i don't understand what this question want . i need to find $B^{n-1}$?

Comment: @Vixf I've wrote a proof of the formula

Comment: $\begin{pmatrix} a_{n+2} \\ a_{n+1} \\ a_n \end{pmatrix}=PD^{n-1}P^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 5 \\ 1 \\ \end{pmatrix}$ should I find $PD^{n-1}P^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 5 \\ 1 \\ \end{pmatrix}$ ?  can you explain why you got this formula? $\begin{pmatrix} a_{n+2} \\ a_{n+1} \\ a_n \end{pmatrix}=B^{n-1}\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 5 \\ 1 \\ \end{pmatrix}$ ? can I just plug in $n=1$ to $\begin{pmatrix}a_{n+3} \\ a_{n+2} \\ a_{n+1} \\ \end{pmatrix}=B\begin{pmatrix}a_{n+2} \\ a_{n+1} \\ a_{n} \\ \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Yes if you find this expression, the last coordinate will be $a_n$.

Comment: thankyou so much! in the end I need to compute $ \begin{pmatrix} a_{n+2} \\ a_{n+1} \\ a_n \end{pmatrix}=PD^{n-1}P^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 5 \\ 1 \\ \end{pmatrix}$ right? in this problem I need to represent all in $a_{n+2}, a_{n+1},a_n$ right? and find condition which is true when $n=1$ that satisfy $\begin{pmatrix} a_{n+2} \\ a_{n+1} \\ a_n \end{pmatrix}=B^{n-1}\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 5 \\ 1 \\ \end{pmatrix}$ ?

Comment: Yes. Here, only the third coordonate of the product interest you and gives you $a_n$. But you can also say seeing the form of the formula that $$ a_n=A\left(-2\right)^n+B2^n+C$$